# How to turn on event scheduler on AWS Aurora MySQL Serverless DB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, serverless, scheduler, amazon-aurora

I'd like to run events on AWS Aurora Serverless MySQL(5.7) DB. Event creation is not a problem (I won't go into it here), but no event is started because (I guess) the global parameter event_scheduler is set to OFF, i.e. the scheduler function is not enabled. (And also the LOG_BIN_TRUST_FUNCTION_CREATORS parameter is OFF, which I don't know how exactly it relates to events, but some posts mention it.)

Turning event_scheduler parameter on failed, because apparently it is not even allowed for the admin user: "Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation".

After scanning the forums on the internet dealing with this topic, and StackOverflow replies, the solution should be a parameter that can be set using the AWS "Parameter group". Unfortunately, even though I set this in vain, the settings are not transferred to the database.

The instructions said something about restarting a service (more specifically a DB instance), but I guess that doesn't apply to Serverless DBs. Alternatively, I don't know how this "restart" can be done, because I couldn't find any console function for it.

In short, can someone explain how to get Aurora Serverless MySQL DB to run events?

[No restart option.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48Zhg.png)
[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqqps.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about AWS Aurora serverless V2, and not the deprecated serverless V1, you can select the serverless instance in the Aurora cluster via the AWS RDS UI, select "Actions" and then "Reboot". I just verified that an Aurora Serverless V2 instance has the "Reboot" option.

Comment: Then it might not be v2, because I don't see such an option.
(I've inserted a picture to the post.)

Comment: And I've also attached a configuration image.

Comment: It looks like you are running serverless Aurora v1. Serverless v1 only supports MySQL 5.7. At the end of 2024 Amazon's general support for MySQL 5.7 will end, and they will start charging you an extra extended support fee for running that version of MySQL. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.VersionPolicy.html I highly suggest you upgrade to Serverless v2, and MySQL 8. You should have received an email from Amazon letting you know about this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Preparations for the migration to MySQL 8 are already in progress. However, I would like to solve this problem before the migration.
So, is there any way to run events in the v1 environment?

Comment: Serverless v1 has a lot of limitations. I'm not sure if it's possible with v1.